# Heroku hosted website using zerigo dns not loading for url without leading www

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, url, heroku

I've seen many questions similar to this but nothing specific to heroku and none of them are working for me.

I am in China trying to access my website that I host on heroku. If I use a VPN and type the domain without www (ie. mywebsite.com) then I can access it. However, if I am NOT behind a VPN then the same URL doesn't work.

In summary:

with VPN

- www.mywebsite.com - works
- mywebsite.com - works

without VPN

- www.mywebsite.com - works
- mywebsite.com - does NOT work!

Any idea how I can fix this so that it works even if I'm not behind a VPN?

Edit: add host output

with VPN ON

```
~ ★ host mywebsite.com   
mywebsite.com has address 174.129.212.2
mywebsite.com has address 75.101.163.44
mywebsite.com has address 75.101.145.87

~ ★ host www.mywebsite.com
www.mywebsite.com is an alias for proxy.heroku.com.
proxy.heroku.com has address 107.21.106.77
proxy.heroku.com has address 50.16.215.41
proxy.heroku.com has address 50.16.215.67
proxy.heroku.com has address 107.22.234.17
```

with VPN OFF

```
~ ★ host mywebsite.com 
mywebsite.com has address 75.101.145.87
mywebsite.com has address 75.101.163.44
mywebsite.com has address 174.129.212.2

~ ★ host www.mywebsite.com
www.mywebsite.com is an alias for proxy.heroku.com.
proxy.heroku.com has address 107.22.233.248
proxy.heroku.com has address 50.16.215.67
proxy.heroku.com has address 50.16.233.102
proxy.heroku.com has address 107.21.95.3
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include the output of `host mywebsite.com` and `host www.mywebsite.com` while connected to VPN and while not connected.

Comment: @ErikA here ya go.

Answer (score 0):

As a guess, the great firewall of china is blocking the Amazon IP address 75.101.145.87, 75.101.163.44,174.129.212.2  but not the ones that the proxy.heroku.com entry uses. I don't think you're going to be able to do anything about it. If you provided the actual domain I could check it from here to see how it looks to me.